# how to print response request in pretty from raw in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, http-post

I am getting out put in this way

```
2016-08-23 11:48:04.944 LogInPage[3340:45237] requestReply: {"account-token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjhmYjI3NDEwZGNkMjQ3ZTY5MTQ1YWE4ZGZhNzY1OWVlIiwiaWF0IjoxNDcxOTMzMDg0LCJleHAiOjE0NzE5MzQ4ODQsImF1ZCI6ImJhbmRvYnJhcy5yb2xsZm9yd2FyZC5uZXQiLCJpc3MiOiJSb2xsIEZvcndhcmQgTExDIiwic3ViIjoiYWNjb3VudDpjb25zdW1lcjpub3JtYWwifQ.4gkE6Qq1TXKEvU9wyBc3aS2L73866TwTxR0sC8mcqjg","consumer":{"id":"8fb27410dcd247e69145aa8dfa7659ee","date-joined":1471933084000,"reward-multiplier":0,"verified":false,"preferences":{"daily-journal":1,"followed":1,"bonus-rolls":1},"contacts":{"name":null,"phone":null}},"user":{"id":"33e4442e9fbc4188a50448864a0bdf20","email":"has@jvnj.co","password":null,"consumer-id":"8fb27410dcd247e69145aa8dfa7659ee","business-id":null,"admin-id":null}}16
```

I want output in this way

```
{

"account-token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjQ0NTk1OTI2ZDRhYzQyMjc4OTliMzBjODQ4NWMxMGZkIiwiaWF0IjoxNDcxOTMwODg4LCJleHAiOjE0NzE5MzI2ODgsImF1ZCI6ImJhbmRvYnJhcy5yb2xsZm9yd2FyZC5uZXQiLCJpc3MiOiJSb2xsIEZvcndhcmQgTExDIiwic3ViIjoiYWNjb3VudDpjb25zdW1lcjpub3JtYWwifQ._PmzVQ4GfoVX2QPBi6wBwslCX-IWV3jUL1lqXihAqW4",

 "consumer": {

 "id": "44595926d4ac4227899b30c8485c10fd",

 "date-joined": 1471930888000,

"reward-multiplier": 0,

 "verified": false,

"preferences": {

"daily-journal": 1,


"followed": 1,
      "bonus-rolls": 1
    }
,
    "contacts": {

  "name": null,
      "phone": null
    }
  },

 "user": {

  "id": "504559b7c57f4a0e9d6453ad18d713e6",

"email": "yryi@uri.com",

"password": null,

"consumer-id": "44595926d4ac4227899b30c8485c10fd",

 "business-id": null,

  "admin-id": null
  }
}
```

**My code is**

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@%@", requestReply,postLength);
//        NSLog(@"Request body %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    }] resume];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean by 'this way'? Please be clear about your question, or at least format your code to be understandable and readable.

Comment: sorry sir  i need in the way of pretty (POST MAN)way as i am getting in raw i should come in seperate lines not mixing up in output

Comment: yes like jason in out put  in my xcode

Comment: Check my answer brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:0 
                                    error:&jsonError];
NSArray *keys=[json allKeys];
NSArray *values=[json allValues];
NSString *milliseconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[json objectForKey:@"consumer"] objectForKey:@"date-joined"]];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([milliseconds longLongValue] / 1000)];
NSDateFormatter *datfrm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datfrm setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [datfrm stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"The date is - %@",strDate);
```

The printed result is

```
The date is - 23/08/2016
```

Above in my code I pass option is zero.So If you pass **option as zero** you **get immutable containers**.

> It means that all arrays will be NSArrays, all Dictionaries will be NSDictionaries, all strings will be NSStrings, and so on, even if the original objects were mutable dictionaries, dictionaries, or strings.

Generally

> Immutable objects are generally safer (no need to worry about a value changing underneath you)

[Serialization](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/property-list-seralization/)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:&jsonError];
       NSLog(@"Response = %@",json);

    }] resume];
```

Comment: @vamsi Welcome brother :-)

Comment: can u help me how to print individual keys and there values

Comment: i mean i am getting date format like this "date-joined" = 1471948172000;        how to convert date formate means like DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: NSDate * myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 1471948172000];

Comment: i have used that before its output coming like this                                "bonus-rolls" = 1;
    "daily-journal" = 1;
    followed = 1;
} contactDict{
    name = "<null>";
    phone = "<null>";
} date48614-03-08 04:13:20 +0000

Comment: You are not even responding me.I updated answer for every seconds that what you ask.Ok brother not a problem.

Comment: i am sorry bro you have done i am trying thats why i didnt see your update once again thank you bro